Blazor app not showing new information after update message via SignalR
I have a Blazor .net 8 Web App where I use Entity Framework Core with SQL Server. I have the following code for my view page:
view.razor.cs:
public partial class View : ComponentBase
{

    [Parameter]
    public int DebtorId { get; set; }
    private Debtor _debtor = new();
    private bool DataLoading = false;
    private HubConnection _hub;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (DataLoading)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            DataLoading = true;

            await RefreshData(true);

            _hub = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/dmhub"))
            .Build();

            _hub.On<string, int>("CUD", (Model, Id) =>
            {

                if (Model == "debtor" && Id == DebtorId)
                {
                    InvokeAsync(() => RefreshData());
                }

            });

            await _hub.StartAsync();

        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        finally
        {
            DataLoading = false;
        }
    }

    private async Task RefreshData(bool? firstrender = false)
    {
        _debtor = await _debtorRepos.GetSingleOrDefaultWhereIncludeAsync(x => x.Deleted == false && x.Id == DebtorId, "Contacts");
        StateHasChanged();
    }

Repository.cs:
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{

    private ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetSingleOrDefaultWhereIncludeAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, string include)
    {
        return await _db.Set<T>().Include(include).SingleOrDefaultAsync(where);
    }
}

View.razor:
<h1 class="">@(_debtor.Name)</h1>

Edit.razor:
I use almost the same .cs file with the edit page as with the view page.
<InputText class="form-control" id="Name" @bind-Value="@_debtor.Name"></InputText>

On all my pages I use @rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false))
Whenever I update the name from for example "test" to "test 1 2 3", the view page receives the message correctly but still shows "test" as name. Only after I hit F5, it shows the new name. I used this same technique in my Blazor Server .net 7 application and it all worked fine there. But now, the new Debtor is only showing after I hit F5.
Anyone who knows what I am doing wrong here?

How are you binding _debtor in the UI ?

@jeb I updated the question. I use <h1>@(_debtor.Name)</h1> on the view page and I use <InputText class="form-control" id="Name" @bind-Value="@_debtor.Name"></InputText> on the AddUpdate page

@jeb on all my pages I use @rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false))

Hi Jeremy, please try to use my updated code, and check it works or not. Thanks.
